# Question regarding handling $\lim \sup / \inf$ in proof of generalized Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm having trouble understanding the way $\lim \sup / \inf$ is handled in the [following proof](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-generalized-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem) for a generalized version of the LDCT. Specifically, my question is with parts (1) and (3). Why can we say that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\inf \int (g_n - f_n) = \int g - \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup \int f_n$$ and
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\inf \int (g_n + f_n) = \int g + \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf \int f_n$$
I can't seem to understand how the $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ appear.

Comment: I think you forgot to write integral before $f_n$ on the RHS.

Comment: If you write the integral, then you can use linearity of integral to get $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left(\int g_n-\int f_n\right) = \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int g_n + \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int -f_n,$$ where $\int g_n$ converges to $\int g$ so $\liminf$ is the same as $\lim$, and note that $\liminf -a_n = -\limsup a_n$. (Actually, $\liminf$ can be dissociated since one sequence converges.)

Comment: @Riemann That makes sense, I don't know why I didn't see that in the first place, thanks. Should I leave this question up? cause now I feel stupid.

Comment: I think you may delete this question, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that $\liminf_{n}(a_n + b_n) = \liminf_{n}a_n + \liminf_{n}b_n$. What is true is that if $a_n \to a$, then $\liminf_{n}(a_n + b_n) = a + \liminf_{n}b_n$. This follows from
$$\inf_{k \geq n}a_k + \inf_{k \geq n}b_k \leq \inf_{k \geq n}(a_k + b_k) \leq \sup_{k \geq n}a_k + \inf_{k \geq n}b_k.$$